# Add csp configuration to .net mvc project

Tags: model-view-controller, content-security-policy

I generated my csp through the page https://report-uri.com/home/generate

I found an article where you can generate a class that inherits the ActionFilterAttribute class to be able to establish the csp, the problem is that I don't know how to add my generated csp to the c# code:

My csp:

```
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js 
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.10/jquery.mask.js 
'https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.0/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js 
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js; style-src 'self' 'unsafe- 
inline' https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.0/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css 
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? 
family=Varela|Open+Sans:700,300,400|Open+Sans+Condensed:300,700|Roboto:100,300
```

My c# code:

```
public class FilterCsp: ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var response = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;
        response.AddHeader("Content-Security-Policy", "script-src 'self'");  //??
        response.AddHeader("X-WebKit-CSP", "script-src 'self'");  //??
        response.AddHeader("X-Content-Security-Policy", "script-src 'self'"); //??
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

How can I add the content of my csp into the c# code?

Is it the correct way? Can I add them to some other file?